# Could a person weigh so much as to cause gravitational lensing?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, estimation, gravitational-lensing

I'm a bit familiar with the concept of gravitational lensing. I also believe that all objects have some gravitational force, even if it's minuscule.

Would an object as massive as a person cause *any* gravitational lensing? Even an extremely miniscule amount from any position?

Bonus points if you somehow quantify the magnitude of this lensing.

I hope the title is ok! It adds a bit of humor and is quite literally the question at hand. We can even assume a 1000lbs person if it helps.

Comment: [An experiment whose name is unfortunate given your (v1) title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_Gravitational_Lensing_Experiment). A search term is “microlensing.”

Comment: @rob Seems like that applies to planets? Looks like we're getting closer!

Comment: I don't like the edited title because it sounds more like I'm wondering about the human limits of obesity rather than gravitational lensing.

Comment: I think Chris Farley has reached the critical mass threshold. Chris's gravitational lensing has made SNL such a unique phenomenon in the 90s.

Comment: Last year, in the series Star Trek Strange New Worlds, the heroes were able to overcome the Klingon cloaking device by using microlensing to detect the Klingon ship.  I guess if it would work for a spaceship, it would work for a person, just on a much smaller scale.

Comment: I suggest the title "Does a person's mass produce measurable gravitational lensing?"

Comment: @DKNguyen yes that is a great title if we're going to go dry. I still prefer my original title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most physics phenomena are continuous - that is they happen in all situations to varying degrees. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens), the angle deflection from gravitational lensing is
$$
\theta=\frac{4GM}{rc^2}=\frac{4G(100\text{ kg})}{(0.25\text{ m})c^2}=10^{-24}\text{ radians}
$$
Where $r$ is the distance of closest approach between the light beam and the massive object (can't get so close that the light beam is simply blocked). That's a pretty small angle deflection.

A laser pointed at a target from very far away would be deflected $10^{−22}$ m
away from the center of the target if said person stood next to the beam's path 100m away from the target.

Comment: Very interesting and it aligns with that I expected! Any chance you can expand the answer to explain the answer in plain terms? Radians are the correct answer I'm guessing but what does that mean in practice? If I'm standing X meters away from a person, how much deflection can I expect from something behind them?

Comment: $10^{-24}$ times X meters. That's what a radian is.

Comment: A laser pointed at a target from very far away would be deflected  $10^{-22}\text{ m}$ away from the center of the target if said person stood next to the beam's path 100m away from the target.

Comment: @AndrewChristensen Awesome! I think you should add that to the answer!

Comment: If a person stood next to a laser that was $10^{24}$ m $\approx 10^8$ light years away, the beam would be deflected 1 m.

Comment: That's 0.1% of the diameter of the observable universe.

Comment: @mmesser314 Wow that's kind of interesting though!

Answer (score 4):

The effect of gravitational lensing on a light beam by a human body will be impossibly small to measure. Note that to get lensing that is easily detected requires the mass of a galaxy cluster (lots bigger that your Aunt Bertha) and a baseline distance of millions or billions of light-years over which the lensing deflection can accumulate (furnishing no way for human beings to set up the baseline path containing Aunt Bertha).

Alternatively, you could try to make the human as heavy as a galaxy cluster but even with poor Aunt Bertha's eating disorder this would be impossible.

If Aunt Bertha were a black hole, you could get lensing under the right conditions, but she would probably object very strenuously to the amount of compression you would need to subject her to.

Answer (score -1):

Their entire field of vision is gravitationally lensed.  Their information is dilated, they just don't recognize it.  Down to what's behind them being ignored as a dimension because they're simply not looking at it.  It might not be detectable by a super collider, but their entire Universe is gravitationally lensed around their field of vision.

It's just hard to notice because every time they try to look to their side to "catch" that lensing, that spot instantly becomes their point of focus, or inverted singularity.  But your mind recognizes the relativistic differences surrounding that inverted singularity, and uses the gradual slide scale of changing wavelengths to infer dimensionality when in reality everything is basically flat.  Everything is dilated around every single particle in the Universe.  Everything is a singularity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).